# MySQL - complicated select through several tables using certain parameter

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if I just have a bad design or what, but I'm having trouble figuring this one out. Here are my tables..

```
BANDS
[pk]bandid
bandname

SHOWS_BANDS
[fk]bandid
[fk]showid

SHOWS
[pk]showid
date
cost
ages

VENUES
[pk]venueid
venuename
street
city
state
zip
[fk]showid
```

Bands can have many Shows, and Shows can have many Bands. Venues can have many Shows.

What I have is a `"bandid"` and with that I want to select the values from the `Venues` and `Shows` table where the `bandid` is linked to a `showid`

In other words, I want to select all of the shows that the band is playing in. For selecting every single show in my database, I just used an `INNER JOIN` on `Venues` and `Shows`.

Here is what I tried (using `"1"` as the known `"bandid"` parameter):

```
SELECT (SELECT showid FROM shows_bands WHERE bandid = 1) AS showid, 
shows.date, shows.cost, shows.ages, venues.venuename, venues.street, 
venues.city, venues.state, venues.zip
FROM shows 
INNER JOIN venues 
ON showid = venues.showid;
```

I tried a lot of other things, but this is the most recent and I don't have the other ones saved. It seems like it would work logically, but it doesn't let me use the `showid` from the `AS` inside the `INNER JOIN ON` clause. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the query that selects every single show:

```
SELECT venues.venuename, venues.street, venues.city, venues.state, 
venues.zip, shows.date, shows.cost, shows.ages, shows.showid
FROM venues 
INNER JOIN shows 
ON venues.showid = shows.showid;
```

Comment: I guess technically, in my program's code, I could just select all of the shows and then filter them out based on the BandID. But if I could just do it with a single SQL Query then I think that seems more efficient..

Comment: In the table definitions, should the Venues.showId be deleted & Shows.venueId be added?

Comment: I'm not really sure since that query causes an error. I updated the post to add the query that select every single show, which I used as a starting point.

Comment: I put one (of many) possible solutions up as an answer. I find the best way to approach these is with pen & paper drawing a bunch of boxes and lines. If you make up some sample data, you can then write out what you want your query result to look like. From there, just figure out how to join the rows together. E.G. if you try to fill out the venues table without removing venues.showid you quickly find you can't fill it out w/out moving that column somewhere else. hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Clearly, showid has no business being in a venues table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to drop venues.showid & add shows.venueid.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE bands (bandid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, bandname VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (bandid)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
mysql> CREATE TABLE shows (showid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date DATE NOT NULL, cost FLOAT UNSIGNED, PRIMARY KEY (showid)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
mysql> CREATE TABLE venues (venueid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, venuename VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, addr TEXT,PRIMARY KEY (venueid)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
mysql> CREATE TABLE shows (showid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date DATE NOT NULL, cost FLOAT UNSIGNED, venueid INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (showid)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

mysql> INSERT INTO venues values (101,"VenueA","Anchorage"),(102,"VenueB","Boston"),(103,"VenueC","Charleston");
mysql> INSERT INTO bands values (301,"BandA"), (302,"BandB"), (303,"BandC");
mysql> INSERT INTO shows values (201,'2000-01-01',NULL,101), (202, '2000-01-02',NULL,102), (203,'2000-01-03',NULL,103);
mysql> INSERT INTO show_bands values (301,201), (302,201), (301,202), (303,202), (302,203),(303,203);


mysql> select * from venues;
+---------+-----------+------------+
| venueid | venuename | addr       |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|     101 | VenueA    | Anchorage  |
|     102 | VenueB    | Boston     |
|     103 | VenueC    | Charleston |
+---------+-----------+------------+
mysql> select * from bands;
+--------+----------+
| bandid | bandname |
+--------+----------+
|    301 | BandA    |
|    302 | BandB    |
|    303 | BandC    |
+--------+----------+
mysql> select * from shows;
+--------+------------+------+---------+
| showid | date       | cost | venueid |
+--------+------------+------+---------+
|    201 | 2000-01-01 | NULL |     101 |
|    202 | 2000-01-02 | NULL |     102 |
|    203 | 2000-01-03 | NULL |     103 |
+--------+------------+------+---------+
mysql> select * from show_bands;
+--------+--------+
| bandid | showid |
+--------+--------+
|    301 |    201 |
|    301 |    202 |
|    302 |    201 |
|    302 |    203 |
|    303 |    202 |
|    303 |    203 |
+--------+--------+


mysql> SELECT bands.*, shows.*,venues.* FROM bands JOIN show_bands ON bands.bandid=show_bands.bandid LEFT JOIN shows ON show_bands.showid=shows.showid LEFT JOIN venues ON shows.venueid=venues.venueid ORDER BY bands.bandid, shows.date;
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
| bandid | bandname | showid | date       | cost | venueid | venueid | venuename | addr       |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|    301 | BandA    |    201 | 2000-01-01 | NULL |     101 |     101 | VenueA    | Anchorage  |
|    301 | BandA    |    202 | 2000-01-02 | NULL |     102 |     102 | VenueB    | Boston     |
|    302 | BandB    |    201 | 2000-01-01 | NULL |     101 |     101 | VenueA    | Anchorage  |
|    302 | BandB    |    203 | 2000-01-03 | NULL |     103 |     103 | VenueC    | Charleston |
|    303 | BandC    |    202 | 2000-01-02 | NULL |     102 |     102 | VenueB    | Boston     |
|    303 | BandC    |    203 | 2000-01-03 | NULL |     103 |     103 | VenueC    | Charleston |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I got it working combining your solution with spencer7593's solution. I think his would have worked with my old database design, but I'm choosing yours as the solution because I think you're right that I should have swapped venueid and showid. Otherwise I have the same venue in the venues table several times (for each of its shows)!

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT v.venuename
       , v.street
       , v.city
       , v.state
       , v.zip
       , s.date
       , s.cost
       , s.ages
       , s.showid
    FROM venues v
    JOIN shows s 
      ON s.showid = v.showid
    JOIN shows_bands r
      ON r.showid = s.showid
    JOIN bands b
      ON b.bandid = r.bandid
   WHERE b.bandid = 1
   ORDER BY s.show_date
```